# Cognitive Complexity of functions should not be too high

Tags: python, sonarlint

When I use SonarLint to check code, it notifies Critical that Cognitive Complexity is a measure of how hard the control flow of a function is to understand. Functions with high Cognitive Complexity will be difficult to maintain.

I use a lot of `if else` statement, but can not use `switch case`.

This is my code:

```
str_time = str_time.lower()
if (bool(re.search(r'\d', str_time)) == True) and ('tối' or 'chiều' in str_time):
    day = re.findall(r'\d+', str_time)[0]
    if int(day) < datetime.date.today().day:
        month = datetime.date.today().month + 1
    else:
        month = datetime.date.today().month
    year = datetime.date.today().year
    day = f'{year}-{month}-{day}'
    return format_datetime(day)
elif 'hôm nay' in str_time or 'hn' in str_time or 'chiều nay' in str_time or 'tối nay' in str_time:
    return format_datetime(datetime.date.today())
elif 'ngày mai' in str_time or 'mai' in str_time:
    day = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
elif 'ngày mốt' in str_time or 'mốt' in str_time:
    day = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
elif 'thứ 2 tuần sau' in str_time:
    num = 7 - datetime.date.today().weekday() + 0
    day = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=num)
elif 'thứ 3 tuần sau' in str_time:
    num = 7 - datetime.date.today().weekday() + 1
    day = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=num)
```

Comment: It would probably help if you added a little explanation of what you're doing (especially since this is an English site). Do you plan to check for each next weekday, e.g. "thứ 4 tuần sau", "thứ 5 tuần sau", etc.? Because that will be a *lot* of repetition, and would be much better served by a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: (Also: does the code currently work properly? Is its output correct? It seems strange, for instance, that some branches return, while some merely set variables.)

Comment: Of course not many people would like to even take a look at that code. It also contains some magic numbers like 7, 0, 1, etc. If I were you I would refactor it and make it more meaningful.

Comment: Changing some of the conditional expressions into simple boolean functions may help as well.  For example, instead of `elif 'hôm nay' in str_time or 'hn' in str_time or 'chiều nay' in str_time or 'tối nay' in str_time:`, have `elif time_is_today(str_time):` then `def time_is_today(str_time):` `return 'hôm nay' in str_time or 'hn' in str_time or 'chiều nay' in str_time or 'tối nay' in str_time:`

Answer (score 1):

Sonar lint is right. It seems your code complexity is high. You should create smaller methods or change the logic. But if that is not possible, just ignore the linter.